# Custom title with Android Annotations

Tags: java, android, android-annotations, android-titlebar

Is it possible to set a custom title with the Android Annotations api? Previously I would call

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title_layout);
```

in the onCreate method, but this doesn't appear to be possible in the @AfterViews annotated method, since it has to be done before the contentView is set. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Have a look This http://androidcodesnippetsblog.blogspot.in/2013/03/custom-window-title-bar-in-android.html

Comment: The method described in the blog refers to the way I used to add titles to activities. The code I put in the question (which is referred to in the blog) must go in the onCreate method, and the requestWindowFeature must occur before the contentView is set. When using AndroidAnnotations it looks like I cant use the onCreate method.

Comment: Guys, you should really check out the AA [wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki).

Comment: I answered the question....did you find the answer on the wiki? Perhaps you could have linked to that page instead of just spamming the generic wiki page which I had already looked through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using com.googlecode.androidannotations, androidannotations-api version 2.7.1. There is a newer release; org.androidannotations, androidannotations version 3.0.1 which contains a @CustomTitle annotation which works perfectly.